# Looking for the "pandas" way to aggregate multiple columns to a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with tables containing a number of image-derived features, with a row of features for every timepoint of an image series, and multiple images. An image identifier is contained in one column. To condense this (primarily to be used in a parallel coordinates plot), I want to reduce/aggregate the columns to a single value. The reduce operation has to be chosen depending on the feature in the column (for example mean, max, or something custom). DataFrame.agg seemed like the natural thing to do, but it gives me a table with multiple rows. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
result_df = DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
  if col in ReduceThisColumnByMean:
    result_df[col] = df.mean()
  elif col in ReduceThisColumnByMax:
    result.df[col] = df.max()
```

This seems like a detour to me, and might not scale well (not a big concern, as the number of reduce operations will most probably not grow beyond a few). Is there a more pandas-esk way to aggregate multiple columns with specific operations to a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all columns by list, get `mean` and `max` and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
result_df = pd.concat([df[ReduceThisColumnByMean].mean(),
                       df[ReduceThisColumnByMax].max()]).to_frame().T
```